# Apache Beam: Coder Inference by TypeDescriptor

Tags: guava, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

In following code, at runtime we perform `((Object)o).getClass()` and pass in instance of class to `getCoder` below to get runtime type of an object. How are we able to get runtime types in this manner when type information is lost due to type erasure? Note `TypeDescriptor` wraps `TypeToken` from Guava.

```
  public <T> Coder<T> getCoder(Class<T> clazz) throws CannotProvideCoderException {
    return getCoder(TypeDescriptor.of(clazz));
  }
```